# obtain all records in table with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

using entity framework how do I obtain all the records in a table?

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
 IEnumerable<UploadedFile> allSalesUploaded = new List<UploadedFile>();
```

so instead of = new List, I am looking for all the records in the UploadedFile table? db.?context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
var allSalesUploaded = db.UploadedFile.ToList();
```

Comment: `db.Set<UploadedFile>().ToList()` if you don't like guessing.